# SpringBoot with server.contextPath to answer during dev at /

Tags: spring-boot

I'm working on Spring Boot app that is always running in the context-path of /a because it is part of larger eco-system of apps. So in the application.yaml we set server.conetxtPath=/a

My question is if it possible to make / redirect to /a instead of having the behavior of return HTTP 404 response?

Comment: Why not just temporarily override context path in dev time via system properties like `-Dserver.contextPath=/`?

Comment: Because I need all the app to work under /a

Answer (score 0):

Add a profile set to dev that overrides context path to /